# Index 1 beyond bounds

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am splitting a string into characters in an array, depending on the character an action is performed. If the textfield is blank or has 1 character in it the app crashed with a NSRangeException. If there are 2 or more characters then it works with no issues, partial code as follows:

```
-(IBAction) text: (id) sender{


    //labelText.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",textField1];
    labelText.text = textField1.text;
    NSString *myString = textField1.text;

    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
        NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
        [characters addObject:ichar];
    }

    //NSLog (@"%@", [characters objectAtIndex:1]);
    //NSLog (@"%@", [characters objectAtIndex:2]);

    one1.text = (@"%@", [characters objectAtIndex:1]);

    if ([textField1.text length] == 0) {
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter number in the box above." message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
        [myAlert release];

    }


    else if ([textField1.text length] == 1){
        NSString *char1 = [characters objectAtIndex:0];
        Charr1 = char1;

    }

    else if ([textField1.text length] == 2){
        NSString *char1 = [characters objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *char2 = [characters objectAtIndex:1];
        Charr1 = char1;
        Charr2 = char2;

    }else if ([textField1.text length] == 3){
        NSString *char1 = [characters objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *char2 = [characters objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *char3 = [characters objectAtIndex:2];
        Charr1 = char1;
        Charr2 = char2;
        Charr3 = char3;


    }else if ([textField1.text length] == 4){
        NSString *char1 = [characters objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *char2 = [characters objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *char3 = [characters objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *char4 = [characters objectAtIndex:3];
        Charr1 = char1;
        Charr2 = char2;
        Charr3 = char3;
        Charr4 = char4;

    }else if ([textField1.text length] == 5){
        NSString *char1 = [characters objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *char2 = [characters objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *char3 = [characters objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *char4 = [characters objectAtIndex:3];
        NSString *char5 = [characters objectAtIndex:4];

        Charr1 = char1;
        Charr2 = char2;
        Charr3 = char3;
        Charr4 = char4;
        Charr5 = char5;
```

Comment: Perhaps try changing the test to examine the arrays count property instead of the length of the text in the textfield and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line in your code crashes your app because if there is a 0 or 1 character in your string then your string you cannot access at location:1

```
one1.text = (@"%@", [characters objectAtIndex:1]);
```

to resolve put your whole code after for loop in following if condition

```
if([characters count] > 0)
{
   // your code after for loop write here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to remove this line:

```
one1.text = (@"%@", [characters objectAtIndex:1]);
```